# Expected number of "trips" for spatial Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

> The appearance of an object of interest in a region of area $x$ units$^2$ follows a (two-dimensional) spatial Poisson process $N$ with constant rate $\lambda$ units$^{-2}$. An observer, who wishes to witness the object, can only view a fixed amount of total area, say $m$ units$^2$, in a single trip.
>
> If distinct areas are visited in each trip, how many trips should the observer expect to take before they have witnessed the object $k$ times?

---

I am not sure how to formulate this problem. I can denote $B_i$ as the region visited in the $i$th trip. If I then denote the total area visited over all trips as $B$, I can write it like so:
$$
B = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^{\ell}{B_i}
$$

Where $\ell$ is the quantity that I want. Specifically, I believe I need the expected value of $\ell$, given that $N(B)=k$. Do you have any hints as to how I can properly formulate this question?

Comment: If the object appears more than once in $B_i$ is that considered one sighting or two?

Comment: I'd consider it as more than one sighting

Comment: There's an issue with the problem. Since you fix the area $x$, there's a positive probability that are fewer than $k$ objects in the entire area. So the answer is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of observing the object on the $i$th trip is equal to
$$P(N(B_i) \ge 1) = 1-P(N(B_i) = 0) = 1 - e^{-\lambda \text{area}(B_i)}$$
since the areas are disjoint, and for a Poisson process the number of objects in disjoint intervals are independent, the number of trips till you observe the object once follows the distribution
$$\text{Geometric}(1-e^{-\lambda m})$$
(we assumed that the $B_i$ have area $m$).
Therefore the number of trips till you observe $k$ objects is the sum of independent geometric random variables, which is a distribution with a name that I'll let you research.

Comment: So, if we let $X_i\sim\textrm{Geom}(1-e^{-\lambda m})$, then observing $k$ objects is $Y:=\sum_{i=1}^{k}{X_i}\sim\textrm{NB}(k, 1-e^{-\lambda m})$, which has expected value
$$
\frac{k(1-1+e^{-\lambda m})}{1-e^{-\lambda m}}=\frac{ke^{-\lambda m}}{1-e^{-\lambda m}}
$$
Am I on the right track now?

Comment: Ya, you've got the idea. Although I think the numerator should be just $k$. The range of the geometric random variables starts at 1, not zero, so the expected value of each $X_i$ is $1/(1-e^{-\lambda m})$.

Comment: @Andrew that being said, my answer assumes that seeing multiple objects in one trip counts as a single sighting. I'd have to think about how to deal with counting that as multiple sightings.

Comment: Try writing the number of sightings as the sum of indicators, where you sum over the number of total objects in the area, and also the number of trips. Then use the fact that conditioned on the number of total objects, the positions are uniformly distributed